# Pytorch no gradient calculated one for variable

Tags: pytorch

I defined 2 variables (D, ht) to received gradients. However after the loss function and backward() calculation, only D has gradients, ht does not have any gradients calculated. Can you please help me to understand why it is the case? thank you.

```python
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable, Function

x = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.random.normal(0,1,(10,10))), requires_grad=False)  # original

# depends on size of the dictionary, number of atoms.
D = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.random.normal(0,1,(500,10,10))), requires_grad=True)

# hx sparse representation
ht = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.random.normal(0,1,(500,1,1))), requires_grad=True)
ld = 0.02
lr = 0.001 # learning rate

# optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([ht,D], lr=lr, momentum=0.9)
optimizer.zero_grad()

loss_ht = 0.5*torch.norm((x-(D*ht).sum(dim=0)),p=2)**2
loss_ht.backward() # back propogation
optimizer.step() # update parameters
```

D has graidents, see below

```python
D.grad.data
```

( 0 ,.,.) =
2.0307e+01 9.9208e+00 4.9194e+00 … -2.3104e+01 -2.6616e+01 -9.8070e-01
3.7742e+01 2.5255e+01 4.5286e+00 … -3.5697e+01 -1.1306e+01 1.9366e+01

ht does not have any gradients. but why? please help. see below.

```python
ht.grad.data
```

AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
----> 1 ht.grad.data

AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘data’

Comment: your code works fine for me. did you try printing just `ht.grad` ?

Comment: @WasiAhmad , you are right. I mess up one line of code that editing ht. it is working when I remove it. thanks.